# "You can expect..." is that "can" necessary?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatical?

> You can expect to receive my message in five days.

I think "can" is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 6):

It's grammatical and in fact it changes the meaning of the sentence.

"You expect to receive my message in five days" is a very weird sentence; it suggests that the speaker can read the listener's mind.

"You can expect to receive my message in five days" is more normal. I am telling you what it is reasonable for you to expect.

It is very common to say "can expect" in this context. You can also say "should expect" to mean roughly the same thing.